# Toplink in clustered environment Exception

Tags: spring, cluster-computing, toplink

***My application using Toplink with Spring and working fine...but when test application on  clustering environment it throwing exception ... 
I have 2 nodes of servers (n1 and n2) when i shutdown serving node(suppose n1) it start throwing below exception... while n2 is serving requests ***

DEBUG [controller.administrator.ManageCustomFieldsController] Trying to find handler for exception superclass [java.lang.Exception]
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.toplink.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:62)
        at oracle.toplink.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:55)
        at oracle.toplink.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:61)
        at oracle.toplink.indirection.IndirectList.buildDelegate(IndirectList.java:202)
        at oracle.toplink.indirection.IndirectList.getDelegate(IndirectList.java:359)
        at oracle.toplink.indirection.IndirectList.isEmpty(IndirectList.java:444)
        at com.soft.web.controller.administrator.ManageCustomFieldsController.transform(ManageCustomFieldsController.java:540)

Any idea about it...?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you serialized a persistent object from one server to the other.  When you do this, any LAZY relationships will become detached.

You need to ensure you have instantiated any relationships that you require.  Or re-fetch the objects from the database.